# Rebuild the decision function of one class SVM in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, libsvm

In order to learn the details of the one class model, I want to know how to reprogram the decision function in sklearn. I checked the decision function here[https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/svm/base.py#L419]. Followed by the function, I found `svm_csr_predict_values`[https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f65d144e3966113d3daec836e443c6d7a5b/sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/svm.h], but there is no definition in this repository.

I also checked the libsvm source code [https://github.com/arnaudsj/libsvm/blob/master/svm.cpp], but got nothing. Also there is no relation between these two repositories.

I also tried to rebuild the decision function like this:

```
model = OneClassSVM(kernel='rbf', nu=0.1, gamma=0.1)
model.fit(X)
ssum = model.intercept_[0]
for i in range(len(model.dual_coef_.toarray()[0])):
    ssum += model.dual_coef_.toarray()[0][i] * ((35-model.support_vectors_[i,3])**2 + (40-model.support_vectors_[i,2])**2)
print math.exp(0.1*ssum-.1)
```

where the number 35 and 40 are picked to test the result.

Is there any mistakes within the codes??

Comment: scikit-learn [internally uses libsvm for support vector machines](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#implementation-details). So there is definitely a relation between them.

Comment: @VivekKumar  Hi, I have tried the methods mentioned in the URL, but the result calculated by the decision function is still not the same as the Sklearn OneclassSVM. What's the problem inside?